# Supply Picasso library function with URLs fetched with AsyncTask

Tags: android, picasso

I am building an activity that is supposed to show movie posters in a grid. Ideally I would do that using the Picasso library. In order to acheive that, I have a `MovieListFragment.java` with the following:

- an inner class `FetchMovieTask` extending `AsyncTask` where `doInBackground()` basically fetches posters images URLs from an API and puts them in a `String[]` array;
- `updateMovieList()` that creates an instance of `FetchMovieTask` and calls `execute()`;
- I create an adapter for the GridView in `onCreateView()`:

  ```
  this.mMoviesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
      R.layout.grid_image_layout, R.id.image_view, new ArrayList<String>());`
  ```

My problem is I can't figure out where to put the Picasso code, how to supply the URLs to the Picasso functions and how to add the images to the grid view. Can anyone help sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is I can't figure out where to put the Picasso code

In the subclass of `ArrayAdapter` that you have yet to write.

> how to supply the URLs to the Picasso functions

In the `getView()` method of the subclass of `ArrayAdapter` that you have yet to write.

> how to add the images to the grid view

Assuming that `R.layout.grid_image_layout` contains your `ImageView`, just put your subclass of `ArrayAdapter` in the `GridView`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Picasso) retrieves the latest [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) posts here on Stack Overflow and shows them in a `ListView`. The subclass of `ArrayAdapter` (the `ItemsAdapter` inner class of `QuestionsFragment`) does as I described:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013-2014 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.picasso;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;

public class QuestionsFragment extends ListFragment implements
    Callback<SOQuestions> {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    RestAdapter restAdapter=
        new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("https://api.stackexchange.com")
                                 .build();
    StackOverflowInterface so=
        restAdapter.create(StackOverflowInterface.class);

    so.questions("android", this);

    return(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Item item=((ItemsAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

    EventBus.getDefault().post(new QuestionClickedEvent(item));
  }

  @Override
  public void failure(RetrofitError exception) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getMessage(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
          "Exception from Retrofit request to StackOverflow", exception);
  }

  @Override
  public void success(SOQuestions questions, Response response) {
    setListAdapter(new ItemsAdapter(questions.items));
  }

  class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    ItemsAdapter(List<Item> items) {
      super(getActivity(), R.layout.row, R.id.title, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      Item item=getItem(position);
      ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(item.owner.profileImage)
             .fit().centerCrop()
             .placeholder(R.drawable.owner_placeholder)
             .error(R.drawable.owner_error).into(icon);

      TextView title=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);

      title.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position).title));

      return(row);
    }
  }
}
```

In `getView()`, among other things, I:

- chain to the superclass to have it inflate my layout for me (plus handle row recycling)
- find my `ImageView` widget in the inflated layout
- tell Picasso to go load the avatar into the `ImageView`